# Can we log Bundle errors?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, error-handling, bundling-and-minification

When using ASP.NET MVC [Bundling/Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) if there is an issue bundling a particular file, then this file will simply be skipped and missed out of the rendered bundle.

So far reasons I know for this are:

- File not found
- Invalid syntax

Is there anyway of logging this so that I can identify why particular files are sometimes not being included?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Syntax Issues'?

Comment: @haim770 Invalid syntax

Comment: @Curt One approach (perhaps overkill, but very customizable) could be a custom bundler. [Here is some example code on Github](https://github.com/MikeSmithDev/LicensedBundler/blob/master/LicensedBundler/LicensedScriptBundle.cs) and you can see on line 44 where you can catch the errors.

Comment: It's not a complete duplicate of [Asp.Net MVC Bundling, best way to detect missing file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23802800/33051) as that only answers half the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the source for `System.Web.Optimization` files that aren't correctly minified should be noted in the rendered output through the `JsMinify.GenerateErrorResponse` method with a comment block as follows:

```
/*
Each Minify Error happens
On a new line
But it's basiclly obj.ToString() on the errors collection
*/
```

But none of the default processors throw (or log) any explicit issues unless your virtual paths are malformed.

Digging around a bit I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25784663/33051) here on Stack Overflow that shows an custom extension method you could use to handle this - you could adapt that to log issues rather than throwing exceptions if you'd like the rest of the application to continue running.

Comment: Thanks Zhaph, however this doesn't cover files which are not found. How can I report on this?

Comment: @Curt Sadly there doesn't appear to be anything that to support that - even ReSharper 8 isn't showing me broken virtual paths (like it does for Views and images).