# What is a good fallback for when MVC Bundling Fails?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification

In production an MVC site occasionally ends up with a broken bundle:

```
<link href="/bundles/css/global.css?v=" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/bundles/js/combined.js?v="></script>
```

Recycling the site will regenerate the bundles and make it work again.

At this stage, I'm not too concerned with the *why*, more what can be done as a fallback for when the bundle generation fails.

The bundles are created thusly (js):

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js/combined.js").Include(
                        "~/js/file1.js",
                        "~/js/file2.js",
                        "~/js/file3.js"));
```

css:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/global.css").Include(
                    "~/css/file1.css",
                    "~/css/file2.css"));
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25784663/304683) looks like a good starting point..